# Not able to set header using retrofit

Tags: java, android, http-headers, retrofit2

I am trying to set the header

```
public static Retrofit getClientWithHeader(String baseUrl) {

        OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(new HttpLoggingInterceptor().setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY));


        httpClient.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
            @Override
            public okhttp3.Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                Request original = chain.request();


                Request request = original.newBuilder()
                        .header(GlobalEnum.PREFS_OAUTH_KEY,"Bearer " + DataManager.getAccessToken(HULApp.getInstance()))
                        .build();

                return chain.proceed(request);


            }
        });

        client = httpClient.build();

        if (retrofit == null) {
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                    .client(client)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();

        }
        return retrofit;
    }
```

But as I checked on server, API call is not receiving the header.
I tried to debug the code by setting the breakpoints, but it was not going inside the header interceptor.

Comment: your condition `if (retrofit == null)` will block the client from being set.

Comment: thanks a lot@MạnhQuyếtNguyễn silly mistake